# Loading DataTables with RequireJS in CakePHP: Issue with DebugKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, datatables

I've reedited this question to keep it as clean as possible. I hope that doesn't bother you.

**My main problem is that the jquery plugin datatables is not being loaded properly in my requirejs setup. (v1.9.4)**

I am also trying to use DT_bootstrap (which extends datatables to bootstrap). When i run my pages the console always tells me that DT_bootstrap failed because $.fn.dataTable is not defined. The problem can not be in DT_bootstrap, because I don't need it to run datatables and if I remove it from my app the error is still the same.
I read here that requirejs is not ready to be normally loaded with requirejs but I've found some people that did end up implementing it successfully, most of them in different ways. So far none of the examples I've found worked for me.

**Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined " (DT_bootstrap.js)
typeof $.fn.dataTable is undefined and it should be a function...**

Before I decide to implement requirejs in my app one of my scripts (general.js) was checking if there were any tables with class "datatable" and when they exist I would run the datatables script assynchronously, which works great.
I would prefer to keep it that way so that I don't load datatables code in all of my app pages, but it doesn't work. I get exactly the same error as if I was trying to load it with requirejs.

Here is my "data-main" script:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "../vendor/jquery/jquery", // 1.9.1
        "jquery.cookie": "../vendor/jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie",
        "bootstrap": "../vendor/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap", // 2.3.2
        "bootstrap-timepicker": "../vendor/bootstrap-timepicker/js/bootstrap-timepicker",
        "jqueryui": "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
        "datatables": "jquery.dataTables", // 1.9.4
        "datatables-bootstrap": "DT_bootstrap",
        "modernizr": "../vendor/modernizr/modernizr",
        "general": "general"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            "exports": 'jQuery'
        },
        "jquery.cookie": {
            "deps": ["jQuery"],
            "exports": 'jQuery'
        },
        "bootstrap": {
            "deps": ['jQuery'],
            "exports": 'jQuery'
        },
        "bootstrap-timepicker" : {
            "deps": ['jQuery', 'bootstrap']
        },
        "datatables": {
            "deps": ['jQuery']
        },
        "datatables-bootstrap": {
            "deps": ['jQuery', 'datatables', 'bootstrap']
        },
        "jqueryui": {
            "deps": ['jQuery']
        },
        "general": {
            "deps": ['jQuery', 'bootstrap']
        }
    }
});

require(
    [
        "modernizr", 
        "jquery", 
        "jquery.cookie", 
        "bootstrap", 
        "bootstrap-timepicker", 
        "jqueryui", 
        "general",
        "datatables",
        "datatables-bootstrap"
    ], 
    function () {
        //  console.log('something here');
    }
);
```

Please also note that:

1. this is how I'm running require.js: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/require.js" data-main="/js/app.js"></script>` (note that the path to the javascript folder starts by "/")
2. if I remove "datatables" and "datatables-bootstrap" my app runs without any errors
3. in my general.js I have other conditions that run jquery plugins assynchronously (all work except datatables)

   example: if calendar element exists, then load jquery plugin calendar script via `$.getScript()`
4. User dcodesmith tried to help me recently (check his answer) and ask me to try his config in my app, which didn't work. Then I tried to use it in a simple website and it worked for that simple app, but same doesn't happen in my cakephp app where javascript folder is referenced as "/js". The main differences I found were: in his app all the files were in the same folder and that doesn't happen on my app (probably related to point 1).
5. I have also tried using `"exports": 'jQuery.fn.dataTable'` or even `"exports": 'jQuery.fn.DataTable'` or `"exports": '$.fn.dataTable'`... all without success
6. As a test, if I remove both datatables scripts from my config and then I run `$.getScript()` the file loads successfully but the jquery plugin is still not defined ($.fn.dataTable) and therefore I still can't use it

Comment: by the way, I'm using datatables version 1.9.4

Comment: So in neither version are you loading general.js with require()? That looks like a problem.

Comment: please add a comment above each require / define call saying what source filie it's in.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I think you want to know the path of the file which is described above in `paths:{}`

Comment: I'm asking for the path of any file containing a require or define function call (or a call to require.config). What files are those calls in? How many files contain those calls? Also, see my first question.

Comment: @LynHeadley, neither version works. These are 2 versions(or tries) of the same file which I load from the html like this `<script type="text/javascript" data-main="main.js" src="/vendor/requirejs/require.js"></script>`

Comment: @LynHeadley, actually when I said neither version works I'm just talking about loading the datatables because everything else works fine on both cases

Comment: Not sure I can help as there are details missing. One thing I will say is that it is very strange to see two requires and a define in the same file. Normally each is in its own file. Also, I don't understand what you're doing with general.js and I don't think you want it there.

Comment: actually the define wasn't suppose to be there, it was something I just tested (I'm changing it back to require). General.js is a script where I do some DOM manipulation. In my first example, the most important detail in general.js is that I check for any table with class "datatable", and only if any such table exists then I launch the datatables script by using `$.getScript('jquery.dataTables.min.js').fail(function({ console.log('datatables failed loading') })` this was working before I implement requirejs, but not now. Apparently the script runs but $.fn.Datatable doesn't get defined

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I think I have the solution for you

Comment: unfortunately still stuck with the same problem

Comment: 1. You don't need the leading '/' in your script tags definition.
2. In your require statement, load dataTables right after jQuery

Comment: 1. I need the slashes, because in my php app I have custom urls and the only way to reference to the js folder is by defining the path from the website root, "/js", or "/vendor" or "/css". 2. still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the source of my problem.

I recreated a website with the same kind of routing and folders as my cakephp app and I finally found something.

I use a debug plugin in CakePHP called DebugKit, that plugin appends 2 scripts at the end of the  of the document. One of them is jQuery 1.8.1 and the plugin's script which is basically a toolbar similar to a horizontal navigation.

I was always told to not worry in removing this instance of jQuery because it was being loaded in a non conflict way, it happens that once I disabled this, my requirejs config finally worked with the plugin datatables as I wanted!

I don't know why the exact reason of this conflict, but I'm quite sure it comes from this part of the code:
https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/master/webroot/js/js_debug_toolbar.js#L59-73

I never noticed this before because I only use the datatables plugin in my admin section and the php debugger plugin is always on when I'm logged as admin.

I'll change the title to include cakephp, might be useful for someone with the same problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was running into the same issue while using requirejs to load carousel plugin: slick.js. After saw your answer, i tried to disable the debug mode and it works. However, do you have any solution to enable debug kit while using the requrejs?

Answer (score 4):

Right, so what I've done is started from the bottom-up and get a bare metal configuration working.

**app.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2",
        "datatables": "jquery.dataTables-1.9.4.min",
        "DT-bootstrap": "DT_bootstrap"
    },
    shim: {
        "datatables": {
            "deps": ['jquery']
        },
        "DT-bootstrap": {
            "deps": ['datatables']
        }
    }
});

require(["jquery", "datatables", 'DT-bootstrap'], function () {

    $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "aaData": [
            ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', 4, 'X'],
            ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.0', 'Win 95+', 5, 'C']
        ],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Engine" },
            { "sTitle": "Browser" },
            { "sTitle": "Platform" },
            { "sTitle": "Version" },
            { "sTitle": "Grade" }
        ]
    });

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="app.js" src="require.js"></script>
    <title>DataTable Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="table_id"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

### Update: Use the shim below and require statement below

```
shim: {
    "jquery.cookie": ["jquery"],
    "bootstrap": ['jquery'],
    "bootstrap-timepicker" : ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
    "datatables": ['jquery'],
    "datatables-bootstrap": ['datatables', 'bootstrap'],
    "jqueryui": ['jquery'],
    "general": ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
}

require(
    [
        "modernizr", 
        "jquery", 
        "datatables",
        "datatables-bootstrap"
        "jquery.cookie", 
        "bootstrap", 
        "bootstrap-timepicker", 
        "jqueryui", 
        "general"
    ], 
    function () {
        //  console.log('something here');
    }
);
```

Comment: I get the same error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined, failing on DT_bootstrap because it didn't load datatables properly. $.fn.dataTable is not defined as a function

Comment: Have you copied and pasted exactly what's on here?

Comment: yes, exactly. I even downloaded jquery 1.10.2, but I need to use 1.9.1

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome + firefox + opera + ie8 + safari, it fails in all of them

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try and help you get this working. Go into the console in Chrome Dev Tools and type `$.fn.DataTable` and tell me if you see anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45700/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-w3jimmy)

Comment: Use this ```"datatables": { 
"deps": ['jQuery'], 
"exports": 'jQuery.fn.dataTable' 
},```